# merging multiple Columns from table1 into one column in table2

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to merge or insert multiple existing columns from Table1 into one column in Table2. I have in table1 the address of costumers, but it's stored in single entities (street address, apt, city, state..etc). What I would like to do is to have all these entities merged into one column as one address for each costumer. I have tried:

```
insert into table2(newAddress) select street_address, city, state, country from table1
```

however, I ger this error "Column count doesn't match value count at row 1". thanks for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you try to insert value for a single field, SQL is expecting you to return only 1 field.  In your case, you're returning 4 fields: `street_address, city, state, country`

I'm not sure of what your final implementation should be but you can try to merge the 4 fields into a single one:

```
insert into table2(newAddress) select street_address + ' ' + city + ' ' + state + ' ' + country AS newAddress from table1
```